# NavigationSplitView in SwifUI not working with nested NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to solve the following problem regarding `NavigationSplitView` in SwiftUI and realmdb:

1. display two overall menu items and a dynamic list within the sidebar (as it is in the apple photos app for iPad for example)
2. every item that gets clicked should display it's destination in the details section of the `NavigationSplitView` within a `NavigationStack`

The implementation currently looks like this:

```
struct OwnerScreen: View {
    @ObservedResults(Project.self) var projects
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(value: "overview") {
                    Label("Overview", systemImage: "square.grid.2x2")
                }
                NavigationLink(value: "departments") {
                    Label("Departments", systemImage: "doc.on.doc")
                }
                Section("Projects") {
                    ForEach(projects, id: \._id) { project in
                        NavigationLink(value: project) {
                            Text(project.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { destination in
                switch destination: {
                case 'overview':
                  OverviewView()
                case 'departments':
                  DepartmentsView()
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Project.self) { project in
                NavigationStack {
                    ProjectDetailView(project: project)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Bitte wählen")
        }
    }
}

struct ProjectDetailView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var project: Project
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                List {
                    if project.pages.isEmpty {
                        Text("Nothing found")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray2))
                    } else {
                        ForEach(project.pages, id: \._id) { page in
                            NavigationLink(value: page) {
                                Text(page.label)
                            }
                        }
                        .navigationDestination(for: Page.self) { page in
                            ConfigurePageView(page: page)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm facing the following issues:

- `Note: Links search for destinations in any surrounding NavigationStack, then within the same column of a NavigationSplitView. A NavigationLink is presenting a value of type “Page” but there is no matching navigationDestination declaration visible from the location of the link. The link cannot be activated.` When I'm clicking on the `NavigationLink` within the `ProjectDetailView`
- `A NavigationLink is presenting a NavigationStack onto a column . This construction is not supported. Consider instead just presenting a new root view which will replace that of an existing stack in the column, or else the column itself if there is no NavigationStack in the target column. If there is a stack in the target column, appending to that stack's path is another option.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, but there are many tutorials on the subject. Follow one and if you have specific questions, read the following and post a question. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Provided more context and much more detail. Hope it now fits the community standards.

Comment: Okay what's more curious: it's working like a charm after clicking on the departments `NavigationLink` and then on a dynamic project `NavigationLink`. After that the warnings disappear and the navigation works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing List's selection binding which is how you show different split view details. See here for info:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview

`.navigationDestination` only works within NavigationStack (this might change in iOS 17)